# Problems in thread with unlimited loop

Tags: java

This is a part of my program.

```
Thread rcv_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("getmsg");
    while (true) {
        /*try {
            Thread.sleep(0);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        if (!getmsg.isEmpty() && socket.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("handle");
            getmsg_ = getmsg.get(0).split(";");
            if (socket.getInetAddress().toString()
                .equals("/" + getmsg_[0])) {
            PW.println(getmsg_[2] + " sent from"
                + getmsg_[1]);
            getmsg.remove(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
});         
rcv_thread.start();
```

It is really so strange.The program never runs in the range of `while(true){}` while I comment the range of `try{}catch{}`
But if I cancel the comment in the range of `try{}catch{}` The loop will successfully runs and runs in the range of `while(true){}`

This is my problem. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: How did you detect entering/not entering `while` loop?

Comment: I use `System.out.println("got if");` but the monitor never shows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop doesn't see changed value without a print statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425130/loop-doesnt-see-changed-value-without-a-print-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Without `wait()` (which is better replacement for `sleep()` here) your loop will consume **ALL** CPU resources and as such the content maybe disabled by the compiler.
The actual reason in your case will vary depending on the architecture/Java compiler/JVM/settings...

Comment: So if I need to run an unlimited loop like `While(true){}` in Thread , I need to add `sleep`() ,right??

Comment: As I said - `wait()` is better than `sleep()` in this content. But the answer is yes. Otherwise your code will consume all available resources and will kill your system.

Comment: But why I just added `System.out.println("got");` after `while(true)` ,the loop will be running?? Why??

Comment: Are you saying that your code with `System.out.println("got");` inside the loop **is** running and producing (a lot of) "got" output lines? In your question you said that it does **not** produce the output without `sleep()` statement?

Comment: After that,I add `System.out.println("get")` instead of `sleep`.But it runs

Comment: I mean if I add nothing in the `while(true){}` like I posted,the loop won't run. But I just added `System.out.println("get")` or `sleep()`,it runs. Why??

Comment: How do you know that the loop does not run? It will only produce the output if your conditions `if (!getmsg.isEmpty() && socket.isConnected()) {` are met. May be the data is not coming but the loop is running and you can't see  it? As it is your loop will consume all you system resources and it may stall other threads that are expected to produce the data.

Comment: I just compared to two results under the `if (!getmsg.isEmpty() && socket.isConnected())` in `true` condition. But if I didn't add `System.out.println("get")`,there is no `System.out.println("handle")` shown in the monitor. If I added `System.out.println("get")` , `System.out.println("handle")` would show in the monitor.Thanks for responding.